# Enabling Basic Authentication in solr 4.3

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, solr, jetty

I am following the link for Enabling Basic Authentication in solr 4.3.

https://lucidworks.com/blog/2015/08/17/securing-solr-basic-auth-permission-rules/

and when o am uploading  **security.json** to ZooKeeper by

```
scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:8983 -cmd putfile /security.json security.json
```

but getting the following Error:

```
    WARN  - 2016-06-16 23:19:28.798; org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread; Session 0x0 for server localhost/127.0.0.1:8983, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
    java.io.IOException: Packet len1213486160 is out of range!
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket.readLength(ClientCnxnSocket.java:112)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:79)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:366)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

Can anyone please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is port number you are using port 8983 which is your host port. Solr run Zookeeper on hostPort+1000, so in your case port number would be  localhost:9983